# Prove or Disprove. Every continuous function on the interval [0,1) is uniform continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If the interval was $(0,1]$ or $[0,1]$ then this would be easy. If the interval were $(0,1]$, I could use a counterexample of $\frac{1}{x}$.

However, I am stuck. I know this is false, but can't think of a counterexample. Maybe $\frac{1}{x-1}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: How is the interval $(0,1]$ special compared to $[0,1)$?

Comment: @goose719, $1/x-1$ is not defined in $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $1/(x-1)$